# Show line numbers in Visual SlickEdit

Tags: slickedit

Does anyone know how I can show line numbers in Visual SlickEdit? I can do this on a per file basis by doing View->Line Numbers, but I'd like to just set it as a mode in the editor and not have to do it for every file I open.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got SlickEdit 2007 (12.x), and AFAIK there's not a way to toggle line numbers for all files at once, but if you're only interested in a few different file types, you can turn on display of line numbers on a per-extension basis in the Display Line Numbers checkbox of the General tab of Tools > Options > File Extension Setup for each extension.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want it for a specific file type?

You can do it for each language or all-languages

Tools->Options->Languages

Here you would select either 'All Languages' or a specific language (I just tried the 'all')

then you would select 'Line Numbers' on the right pane.

Comment: This answer was for SlickEdit2010 (15.X) but I think it has been possible for a few years

Comment: Just confirmed that this works in SlickEdit2013 (v18.0.1.2 64-bit)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using SlickEdit 2013 (v18.0.1.2 32-bit)
use
Tools -> Options -> Languages -> All Languages -> view 
mark the check box line numbers

Comment: Works for SlickEdit Pro 2014 (v19.0.2.5 64-bit). This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

**For SlickEdit Version 12.0.3.0 (Windows)**

> Tools -> Options -> File Extension Setup -> General (Tab)

You will see, Display line numbers check box

**For SlickEdit 2012 (v17.0.2.0 64bit) (Linux)**

> Tools -> Options -> Languages -> Languages -> View

You will see, Line numbers check box